# Is it possible to transform $\frac{n}{x^2(1-x)}$ into $\frac{n}{x(x-1)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to transform/simplify the expression $\dfrac{n}{x^2(1-x)}$ to get $\dfrac{n}{x(x-1)}$, where $x = 1/p$ and $p = 1/x$?

I am really having trouble with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are claiming that

$$\frac{n}{x^2(1-x)}=\frac{n}{x(x-1)}$$

You are claiming that $$\frac1{x}=-1$$ or $n=0$ which is not true in general.